# Some advice on inorganic textbook

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, periodic-trends, organometallic-compounds

I'd like to have some advice on Inorganic textbooks.

I've already consulted some books (Kettle, Drago, Keiter, Cotton) and they are all very useful, but now I'm searching for a textbook which focuses deeper on the relationships between **electronic configurations, periodic properties and reactivity**.

I'd like to have a guideline which explain why some elements are more inert than others or their affinities but based on the description for example of the shielding properties and kind of valence electrons.